# Equality of functions from a empty set to a non empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Consider two sets $A$ and $B$, where $A$ is empty and $B$ is non-empty. Considering following functions,
$$f:A \rightarrow B$$
$$g:A \rightarrow B$$

How can one prove or disprove that $f=g$?

It can be shown that both are similar to the extent that domain and codomain are identical. But, the third condition for equality is that for each element $a \in A$, $f(a) = g(a)$. 
I think, third condition does not apply because it cannot be evaluated due absence of any elements in $A$. By does not apply I mean that it does not affect equality of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: If we want to show $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x \in A$, but then A is empty then the result is true vacuously, perhaps?

Comment: On the contrary, for every element of $A$ (all none of them), the functions are equal. Indeed, there is only one function from the empty set, namely the empty function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negation of "for all $a \in A$, $f(a) = g(a)$" is "there exists $a \in A$, such that $f(a) \neq g(a)$". Can you find an $a \in A$ for which $f(a) \neq g(a)$?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Both $f$ and $g$ are subsets of the set $A\times B$. What is this set?

Comment: I see that it is an empty set. Here is another explanation, suppose $f =g$ is false. Then it follows that there exists $a \in A$ S.T. $f(a) \ne g(a)$. For this to be True, there has to exist atleast 1 element in $A$, which is false. Thus $f=g$ must be True. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, your proof is also correct. Any statement of the form "there exists $x\in A$", where $A$ is the empty set, is false.

Answer (score 0):

A function $h: A \rightarrow B$ must assign a unique element from $B$ to every element of $A$. However, when $A = \emptyset$, this means that there is precisely one function in the set of functions from $A$ to $B$, namely the empty function. So the result holds trivially.